# Hey moderators: worse or better to flag a whole chain of comments?

Tags: discussion, flagging, comments

moderators. Recently, I've been flagging old, obsolete comment threads for cleanup. (You probably noticed.) I'm wondering, though, if it's easier for you if I just flag the top comment (or maybe even post to which all the comments are attached), or if it's more useful with the tools the site provides to flag each individually. What's less work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general when I get a flag on a comment in a thread I take a look at the whole thread to decide what to do. That may be the whole thread, some comments, the comment, or none at all, but a single flag is sufficient, I never delete them from the mod tools.

Comment: Thanks; I'll just flag the most obvious one to me then, and save you having to clear the flag from the rest.